# Azure Data factory with Database on ubuntu VM

Tags: oracle, azure, virtual-machine, azure-data-factory

I have a VM that host an oracle database in an Azure VM
I want to connect it with the data factory, it's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No, it is not possible.

**Reason:** Self-hosted integration runtime requires Windows OS.

Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime (self hosted) is currently only available on windows (see system requirements at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717).

[image]

For more details, refer [Create and configure a self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites)

Comment: thanks for your response this one can help https://github.com/oracle-quickstart/oci-azure-interconnect ????